# Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on a set $A$ and let $a, b, c \in A$. Prove that if $a \in [ b ]$ and $c \notin [ a ]$, then $c \notin [b]$.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, equivalence-relations

Let $a,b\in A$, and assume $a \sim b$. Let $c\in [a]$. This means $c\sim a$. Since $c\sim a$ and $a\sim b$, so therefore $c\sim b$, which means $c\in [b]$.

Would this be the correct way to show a contradiction?

Comment: There are four possible things that can happen. 1)$c\in[a],c\in[b]$ 2)$c\not\in[a],c\in[b]$ 3)$c\in[a];c\not\in[b]$ 4)$c\not\in[a],c\not\in[b]$.  You need to rule out 2).  You ruled out 3).

Comment: $c\not \in [a]$ is your *CONDITION*; not your *RESULT*.  To do a proof by contradiction you assume your *RESULT* is not true.  Your result is $c\not\in [b]$.  So assume $c \in [b]$ so $c\sim b$.  And $a\sim b$ so $b\sim a$ (symmetry--BTW you should for practice be more explicit in giving reasons) and $c\sim b$ (by assumption)  and $b\sim a$ so $c\sim a$ (by trans) so $c\in [a]$ which contradiction our CONDITION (which we *WERE* given and can assume it true because God told us so-- we have not such assurance about our result which was utterly unknown.)

Comment: Why is this thread being closed?  The OP properly formatted the question.  A full attempt has been given.  This doesn't look like a question that needs further context.

Answer (score 2):

Your "proof" is incorrect. What you have shown is instead the converse, which is not equivalent to the original statement.

To prove by contradiction, we assume that the **conclusion** is false, i.e. $c \in [b]$. Since $a \in [b]$ and $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, we have that $[a] = [b]$, so $c \in [a]$. This contradicts our hypothesis that $c \notin [a]$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $a \in [b]$ and $c \not \in [a]$.  Further, suppose for contradiction that $c \in [b]$.  Then since $a \sim b$ and $c \sim b$, we have by transitivity that $c \sim a$, a contradiction, since $c \not \in [a]$.  Therefore, we have that $c \not \in [b]$, as desired.